# Flow union type with exact object types gives 'property is missing in [type 1]'

Tags: flowtype

I have a function that accepts a union two disjoint exact types, and constructs a new object. The [react documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types) indicates that with disjoint exact types, I should be able to infer the type by checking for the existence of a property. However, this doesn't appear to be working -- my else branch indicates that the properties are missing on one of the types.

```
type Sid = {|
  val: string,
  id: number
|};

type Entity ={
  idOrName: Sid | string,
  optionalDescription: ?string
}

const createEntity = (idOrNameAndDescription: Sid | {| name: string, description: string |}): Entity => {
  if (idOrNameAndDescription.val) {
    return {
      idOrName: idOrNameAndDescription,
      optionalDescription: null
    }
  } else {
    return {
      // These next to lines fail, saying:
      // "Flow: Cannot get `idOrNameAndDescription.name` because 
      // property `name` is missing in `Sid`
      idOrName: idOrNameAndDescription.name,
      optionalDescription: idOrNameAndDescription.description
    }
  }
}
```

See the comment in the else/return statement. The errors given are:

```
Cannot get idOrNameAndDescription.name because property name is missing in Sid [1].

 [1] 60│ const createEntity = (idOrNameAndDescription: Sid | {| name: string, description: string |}): Entity => {
       :
     65│     }
     66│   } else {
     67│     return {
     68│       idOrName: idOrNameAndDescription.name,
     69│       optionalDescription: idOrNameAndDescription.description
     70│     }
     71│   }


Cannot get idOrNameAndDescription.description because property description is missing in Sid [1].

 [1] 60│ const createEntity = (idOrNameAndDescription: Sid | {| name: string, description: string |}): Entity => {
       :
     66│   } else {
     67│     return {
     68│       idOrName: idOrNameAndDescription.name,
     69│       optionalDescription: idOrNameAndDescription.description
     70│     }
     71│   }
     72│ }
```

However, as `.val` was not defined flow should know that it is of the other half of the union and `name` and `description` are defined.

I've also tried using `if (idOrNameAndDescription.val != null)`, which makes both of the branches of the if statement invalid as well as `if (typeof idOrNameAndDescription.val === 'string')`, which results in an even uglier error.

Is this a flow bug or am I missing something?

Comment: A second and related issue is if I add the following code:

`const isSid = idOrNameAndDescription.val != null`

I get an error: 
```Error:(85, 43) Cannot get `sidOrNameAndDescription.val` because property `val` is missing in object type [1].```

For whatever reason `const isSid = sidOrNameAndDescription.val ? true: false;` works, but that just seems bizarre to me.

Comment: You can solve this problem using disjoint unions: https://flow.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions/